Samsung S21 FE disconnects from network
Not sure if this is the place to ask, but just in case.
My phone has started to suddenly disconnect from the mobile network without anything happening to cause it. Following some advice Online (Removing Sim, Force Stopping the SIM Toolkit app, resetting connections, turning phone off, inserting SIM again, turn back in) but it barely makes a difference.
Does this sound like a hardware problem or as something that could be solved through software? Any response is more than welcome.

Tried with a second SIM? Also try in different locations with both SIMs
